# Rename [vietnam-citizens] to [vietnamese-citizens]

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging

Shouldn't [vietnam-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vietnam-citizens) be renamed to [vietnamese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vietnamese-citizens)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're right and I just renamed the tag.

Comment: Thanks. You can mark this question as [status-completed]. :)